# What is the best way to display user company role and application role when logged in to the application

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design, responsive-design, content

An application having two roles i.e Company Role and Application Role based on which different sections of the application are accessible to the person.
Company Role describes either Admin or Users whereas Application Roles describes the functional role of the user in the company.

For Eg,
In a company, there is a person who has Company Role as User and Application Role as Accounts and HR. 
Now when the person logged in the application, message or pop up or submenu should be displayed to provide the information of the roles assigned to the users and different menus will be accessible based on the Application role.

I can either display the roles assigned information in the pop-up or as a message "You are logged in as xx role" when a person is logged in or I can provide an option in the submenu for it.

What is the best way to display the roles assigned information to the person having multiple Application Roles along with the Company role when logged in the application?

Comment: Do you have an element on the screen that is related to the user, e.g. their username, or an avatar?

Comment: Yes i have an avatar under which username is displayed.

Comment: Can you also use (slightly) different styling for different roles?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions about how your screen is designed, but:

**Show a panel between when the user clicks on the avatar and when they end up on the profile settings** (first wireframe, below)

Or,

**Provide an 'i' (info) icon with associated tooltip next to the avatar/username.**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs8RVv.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would have small icons (one per role) underneath the username that of course would have appropriate tooltips with the role.  The big trick would be to come up with icons that would be easily understood = identifies role easily.  And you could have it a user preference whether to always show the icons, or have them just appear if they click on a "roles" link under the username.

Answer (score 0):

I would question, the need to display the company role on the screen. It is the user login, and he/she know their role already, and that role changes only once a year at the max, so just showing the application role should be fine.

[image]

Comment: what if they have multiple roles?

Answer (score 0):

we can display their **role** somewhere under my profile section with a list of **permission** available for that role, no need to display in front always.

In case the User has multiple roles then it has to login with different credentials or
a better way is to create a new **role** based on a new set of **permissions** given to the user, so a user can use the single credential.

Answer (score 0):

Please find a wireframe below:
[image]

Comment: Could you expand on this answer a bit?